# Web pages not showing after replacing 'sqlite3' in gem file with gem 'pg'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I used gem 'sqlite3' in my gem file then I replaced it with gem 'pg'. Now none of the web page are showing. Replacing gem 'sqlite3' is not working either. How can I fix this?

Comment: have you changed your database configuration in database.yml file ??

Answer (score 0):

In my Gemfile, i  replacee `gem 'sqlite3'` with:

```
group :development, :test do

   gem 'sqlite3'

end

group :production do

   gem 'pg'

end
```